# UIImageView.Image to mail attachment with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimage, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, email-attachments

I am new to MonoTouch and I am trying to send an email with an image as attachment that a user will tame from camera or pick from gallery.

I have created the program and it runs correctly (I have an imageview controller which loads an image from uiimagepicker to imageview. Then I call `MFMailComposeViewController` but I don't know how to pass the image from imageview to `addAttachmentdata` method.

I suppose first I have to save the image from imageview as a file but I don't know how to do it and I can't find documentation for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to turn the `UIImage` into an `NSData`, e.g. using `AsPNG` or `AsJPG`, then use the right **MIME** type for the image. Here's an example:

```
MFMailComposeViewController email = new MFMailComposeViewController ();
// any UIImage will do
UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile (".../anyimage.png");
email.AddAttachmentData (img.AsPNG (), "image/png", "image.png");
email.SetSubject ("Photo from my iPhone");
email.SetMessageBody ("Here's the attachment!", false);
controller.PresentModalViewController (email, false);
```

**Note**: the `"image.png"` is a [suggested](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMailComposeViewController/addAttachmentData%3amimeType%3afileName%3a) file name given to the recipient email software (i.e. it's not a local file in your device and does not need to match anything that exists).

Comment: yes but how will i turn the image from imageview control to NSData?

Comment: sorry now i saw your NOTE i will try it and see if it works for me

Comment: You already have that answer in your own question ;-) `UIImageView.Image` has a `Image` property of type `UIImage`. So `imageView.Image.AsPNG ()` with return you an `NSData` instance that you can use in the call to `AddAttachmentData`

Comment: i'm trying it but i'm trying to figure it out how to turn the image that exists in imageview to NSData. thanks for your answer