# Xamarin forms iOS default mail app Behavior

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

As per the requirement of the project I need to have the page which should behave as the default Apple Mail app on the iPhone. 
Attaching a gif that I have created for the same.
I tried using the plug in https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup 
but I couldn't achieve the exact same behavior where the background shrinks and expands as the modal pop up is dragged.Any leads, examples or demos will be really helpful. [image: Attached gif]

Note: I am using Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: You can attach images to emails using the built-in `MFMailComposeViewController`, have you tried that? No use reinventing the wheel. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9129374/3850012). You can also do something similar on Android by using the default Android `Intent` to send email (which will use its own animations).

Comment: No, I guess you got it wrong, I don't want to send an email from my app.
I have a button on a page, on click of the button, a page should open as Modal, exactly how it opens when you click on compose email icon in iPhone default email app.

Comment: Oooo ok I understand now. You just want the animation that the email modal uses?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what I am looking for.

Comment: I found some projects can achieve that, but in Objective-C. [Implement animation like iPhone default mail app compose mail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33074326/5474400), [Replicating the style of the iOS Mail App's Compose Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29040354/5474400) . Hope those help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new Xamain Forms update. i.e. after iOS13
The model behavior has became the default model behavior for Xamarin iOS.

When you do.
Navigation.PushModalAsyn(<your_page_here>).

It gives the above (gif) behavior.